# gfortran Error: Missing leading left parenthesis in format string

Tags: gfortran

I got the errors from gfortran:

```
     write(*,'ERROR in subroutine rddist ')                                
               1
```

Error: Missing leading left parenthesis in format string at (1)

io-cfs.f:6574.41:

```
 >    (nint(MOD(cld_scale*1000000.0, 1000000)) .NE. 0)) THEN               
                                     1
```

Error: 'a' and 'p' arguments of 'mod' intrinsic at (1) must have the same type

Can you let me know what it means and the solutions? Thanks a lot.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `write(*,'ERROR in subroutine rddist ')` is not an instruction to write the string `'ERROR in subroutine rddist '`.  The second argument to the write routine is a format string which ought to begin `'(` and end `)'`.  Since your format string doesn't begin properly the compiler found an error there.  What you probably meant to write was:

```
write(*,*) 'ERROR in subroutine rddist '
```

Now check the Fortran documentation for 'edit descriptors' to learn about the second argument to the `write` command.

Second: The `mod` instrinsic function requires that both its arguments have the same type (and kind too).  You have given it a real number `cld_scale*1000000.0` and an integer `1000000`.  Cast one of them to the other's type according to the type you want the result to be.  For type casting check out the functions `real` and `int`.

Comment: Thanks. I also can be print *, 'ERROR in subroutine rddist '. I correct the 1000000 to 1000000.0 and it works. Yes. Both its argument should have the same type and kind.

Comment: Well, how about `write(*,'("ERROR in subroutine rddist")')`. Besides, `write(*,*) 'ERR...'` prints a leading space while the former version does not :)